# Polaris Synopsis (Coverity on Polaris)

Tags: python, polaris

I am very new to this tool. Just wondering if it has API for creating the user or retrieve all users. I read the documentation but not really sure about the response since it has no sample responses from the REST API.

Please refer to this link for the API Documentation:
https://sig-docs.synopsys.com/polaris/topics/t_api-create-project-user-role.html

Anyone who could answer my question would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

I haven't tried since I don't have an account yet in the Polaris.